# PHP Exec() or System() Causes 500 Error

Tags: php, system, exec

A fairly simple problem, I think. Here's my testing code (obviously I'll add security precautions when I'm writing this for real) -

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['url']) && !empty($_POST['url'])) {
        system('wget --no-parent --timestamping --convert-links --page-requisites --no-directories --no-host-directories -erobots=off '.$_POST['url']);
} else {
    echo '<form method="post"><input type="url" name="url"><input type="submit"></form>';
}

?>
```

Is there some module in PHP or Apache2 that I need to enable/install for this to work? I'm visiting this page through the browser, if that helps. This happens even when the command has not been called yet (that part of the `if` statement is not run), and the 500 Error goes away if I comment out the system() or exec() line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me, kindly check if `system` function is disabled for you. You can use `ini_get('disable_functions')` to check if it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your supplied code; at the end you've placed the dot at the wrong place:

```
 '.$_POST['url']);
```

instead of

```
 .'$_POST['url']);
```

Comment: I've copied your exact code, and I get a white page because I've disabled the system()-command, but no error at all. What do you want to accomplish? Can't you use the PHP cURL library or the function file_get_contents() instead?

Comment: I'm trying to download a page and all it's dependencies into a directory, and I was advised that wget is the best way to do that. Can you think of any other ways?